# How did Frank Gallagher end up in Mexico?

Tags: plot-explanation, shameless

At the end of the final episode of the second season of *Shameless* (S2E12), Estefania hits Frank on the head with a frying pan and the guys carry him to the backyard. Later, he is buried in snow.

But at the beginning of S3E01, Frank wakes up in Mexico. How did he get there?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Nobody knows (including Frank)

Frank disappeared and he has no idea where and where he is:

> -Where am I? 
> - Juarez. 
>   - Mexico? Did I miss Christmas? 
>   - Christmas? You almost missed Easter.

And later on when he was talking with the Customs officer:

> Every once in a while, A couple of drinks can get out of hand.
>   But when it happens, the next morning, You have to pick yourself up, dust yourself off, And get right back on the horse.
>   Am I right, or am I right? Just let me cross.
>   I won't tell anyone.
>   I promise.

[Source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=shameless-us&episode=s03e01)

From Fiona's reaction ("When I was 9, he disappeared for a year") we know, that such things tend to happen.

Answer (score 3):

In the credits at the end of the season you see him get up and start wandering off. The 130 some odd days between are left blank intentionally most likely for two reason; firstly, frank doesn't remember either, and it leave the audience with something to think about, like you are, and second, it gives them some plot lines to possibly use in the upcoming season.

Comment: Do you have some evidence to support your theories?

Comment: @TylerShads - did you check the username of the person who wrote this answer?  Isn't that a primary source?